# Twilio program send and wait for reply: How to approach?

Tags: python, flask, redis, twilio, worker

Hey guys I was hoping I could come here to ask for input on how to approach sending a user a text message and then waiting for a reply using **twilio, flask, and redis rq**. In my research, I've found that the process requires using a background worker to either continuously check for a reply or, if designed properly, check a database field for a certain status for example.

My question is, with the tools I mentioned before, what is the best way of achieving this functionality? As someone who hasn't done asynchronous task management, I'm having trouble understanding where does a task scheduler like redis rq come into the equation of waiting for a user's response to a sms text.

Answer (score 2):

I work at Twilio and also code in Python. I never used redis queue but I've used Redis Pub/Sub in the past and this seems like a good approach in my opinion. I've found [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-microservice-python-twilio-redis-pub-sub) from last year showing how to create a simple sms micro service with flask, redis pub/sub and twilio. Let me know if this is helpful or if redis queue is mandatory so I can help you better.

Comment: Hey vvenance thanks for the reply. I've never heard of Redis Pub/Sub but after reading the blog it seems like a pretty useful alternative to what I was originally thinking. How do you think I can use it in my project, where messages will be sent to users over a span of some weeks, with some messages needing a reply from the individual user?

Comment: I think you can use this approach in your project but I would tend to go for @yvesonline solution. I can provide more detailed answer if you tell me which messaging functionality you would like to use but I would also take advantage of the callback url you can provide to Twilio and either check Twilio messaging history with a specific user or store a status in database. Let me know if you use programmable SMS or another of our features so I can tell you the workflow I'd go for

Comment: Thanks again vvenance for getting back. I'm thinking @yvesonline solution is also the preferable way to go and I am using programmable SMS. Via the db solution, I'm guessing I'd have to add fields to the user table on whether they had been sent a certain message or not? Also, how can I take advantage of the callback url like you say? I was originally using Twilio StudioFlow but a scheduling functionality is needed which is why I proposed redis rq.

Comment: If you go for the db solution: add the fields you need to the user model or to a related user_sms model if you need to track many of them. Where you can take advantage of callback url is that it sends you updates on the status of your message, and it's better to update your database when you are sure about how the whole process went so your data is consistent. Here is the [webhook doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks) and here an example of [sending an SMS with a callback url in python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks#type-2-status-callbacks)

Comment: The other thing I mentioned is checking Twilio messaging history. In your use case I would use the **List message matching filtering criteria** functionality with a search on your user's phone number. [docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python). Pros: no need to change the db. You are sure about the data you are evaluating. You can change database type without code updates (switching from SQLite to PG SQL won't break your code anyway) Cons: adds processing time and 1 API call, so don't use this approach if you need to do it quickly

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't use a queue approach here, a database approach, e.g. a [key/value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) for quick lookup (I've used DynamoDB for this quite a lot but normal Redis works too), would make more sense in my eyes.

The flow would be similar to this:

- Use [Twilio's REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) to send out a text message to a user.
- Store that the text message was sent out in the database (and any additional information you might want to record, e.g. timestamp), the phone number you've sent it to becomes the key in the database.
- Wait for a reply from the user using [Twilio Programmable SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python), i.e. essentially this is an endpoint in your Flask app which you connect to the webhook of your number in Twilio (there's an example in the documentation).
- When a text message is received first look up the user in database using the phone number and then process accordingly if found or not.

Comment: Hey yvesonline thanks for the reply. I currently have only a user table in my db with phone num as an id. Would this method work by adding new fields for each question (Sent/Not Sent) and programming accordingly? Or would I have to design a database table for the text messages and then establish the relationship between the user and message tables? I'm currently using Flask SQLAlchemy w/ sqlite. Also would it be best for the process of checking the db table to be handled by a RQ worker?

Comment: If you already have a database then you can use it, it's only about storing that the user / phone number has been contacted. I don't see any benefit of checking the database with a worker. Especially with SQlite which is restricted already, if you scale up you'll need to switch from that anyway, to a proper SQL database or a key/value store.